# Oracle MAF social media sharing and the default share panel

Tags: java, android, eclipse, oracle-maf

I am writing an application using Oracle MAF and need to implement a share system.
I have seen in other apps a default "Share with..." context that seems to be built in to Android

Example from a Samsung s6, from within the Gallery app (I have seen this within other, 3rd party apps as well):
[share interface from android 6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bK0RH.png)

From research it seems that if I were writing an Android only app using say, Android studio, I would have access to a method to trigger this "Share with..." popup. However in all of the examples I have found they call `startActivity()`. Which I cannot find a way to do from within MAF (I think because I can't access things like views and activities?).

So is anyone aware of a way to activate this "Share" context from within MAF?

Please note I do understand I could implement my own social media sharing popup from within my view (I write my UI's with html so it wouldn't be too hard). But I would prefer to trigger this built in popup as it offers a lot more functionality than I could code myself, and also would save a lot of time manually coding these sharing options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle MAF runs inside an Apache Cordova Wrapper. MAF is called a"hybrid" mobile application and therefore it access the underlying OS via the wrapper. I would check if Apache Cordova exposes this API. If it does not then I do not think Oracle MAF can access it. You might also check and see if this call can be made via JavaScript - MAF can access JS libraries. Or, check if Cordova can expose this as a custom plug-in. If so adding a custom plug-in to MAF is easy.

Comment: Great ideas, how would I go about checking these things? I'm not sure where to look to find out, for example, if the call could be made via JavaScript. I hadn't thought to look into plugins either, I will investigate this further. I did also realize later that this might not be exposed because there may not be an equivalent on iOS.

Comment: Start reading docs at apache cordova: cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest Also perhaps post Q's there. You might try posting Q's to Oracle MAF community forum: community.oracle.com/community/oracle-mobile/oraclemaf

Comment: Thanks, I'll check all that out. Sadly I have no luck on the oracle boards, and tend to post here after getting no response. I'll reply here if I figure anything out.

Comment: Apache Cordova Plugin was ultimately the correct path. I got the desired outcome with [this plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing "Apache Cordova Social Sharing Plugin"). I installed it by following the Oracle MAF documentation on 3rd party plugins. Thanks for putting me on the right track!